# Audio fade in/out

Tags: android, audio

I would like to be able to take an audio file and add a fade in/out effect at the begining/end of the file and save it with these effects. is it possible to do without the use of ffmpeg (license issue)?

Comment: find the duration of the audio file and put fade in the beginning and fade out at the end.